# Edit TextFile after written in VB

Tags: vb.net, file, search, text, edit

I am using Visual Basic 2010 to make a program that simulates parking.
When a new car arrives, i writes text to a txt file with the following format:

#

LicensePlate

FullName

ArrivalDate

ArrivalTime

DepartDate

DepartTime

#

And continues with the above format.

How do I let the person find that section by entering their license plate, then it brings up that section so they can enter their departure details?

Thanks!

Comment: please be clear. Those fields are written in a txt file already? and you want to retrieve data by LincensePlate?

Comment: Yes Exactly, i want to display the whole section (in between the "#") and display all content in that section in seperate textboxes...

Comment: so you mean there'll be

`LicensePlate:00001

FullName:MyName

ArrivalDate:08122015

ArrivalTime:0500

DepartDate:08122015

DepartTime:08132015` and you want to retrieve the `00001, MyName... ` etc?

Comment: Exactly, but they wont have the Name before hand, it'll just be numbers and the name.

Comment: I got your point, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write data in normal TXT file. Instead use an XML file. You have XML parsers available for faster fetching.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to use TXT as a friend wants it in TXT.

Comment: Then you might read all the text and split it as per your need and then find the id. And keep this text in your memory so you dont need to read all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for that. I used console as a sample. See codes below.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim blnFound As Boolean = False

        Console.WriteLine("LicensePlate: ")
        Dim strLicensePlate As String = Console.ReadLine()

        Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("TextData.txt")
        Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf("" & strLicensePlate)
        If index >= 0 Then
            blnFound = True
        End If

        If blnFound = False Then
            Console.WriteLine("FullName: ")
            Dim strFullName As String = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("ArrivalDate: ")
            Dim strArrivalDate As String = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("ArrivalTime: ")
            Dim strArrivalTime As String = Console.ReadLine()

            Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("TextData.txt")
                WriteData(strLicensePlate, strFullName, strArrivalDate, strArrivalTime, w)
            End Using
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("DepartureDate: ")
            Dim strDepartureDate As String = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("DepartureTime: ")
            Dim strDepartureTime As String = Console.ReadLine()


            Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("TextData.txt")
            For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
                If lines(i).Contains(strLicensePlate) Then
                    lines(i + 4) = "DepartureDate:" & strDepartureDate
                    lines(i + 5) = "DepartureTime:" & strDepartureTime
                    File.WriteAllLines("TextData.txt", lines)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            Display(strLicensePlate)
        End If

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WriteData(ByVal strLicensePlate As String, ByVal strFullName As String, ByVal strArrivalDate As String, _
                    ByVal strArrivalTime As String, ByVal w As TextWriter)
        w.WriteLine("#")
        w.WriteLine("LicensePlate: {0}", strLicensePlate)
        w.WriteLine("FullName: {0}", strFullName)
        w.WriteLine("ArrivalDate: {0}", strArrivalDate)
        w.WriteLine("ArrivalTime: {0}", strArrivalTime)
        w.WriteLine("DepartureDate:")
        w.WriteLine("DepartureTime:")
    End Sub

End Module
```

The `WriteData` method is for writing the data when a car arrives. As you can see, the `DepartureDate` and `DepartureTime` is empty. Getting the `text.IndexOf` is to know whether the `LicensePlate` entered already exist. If it does not exist yet then index returns `-1`. If it exists, the user is asked for the departure date and time. And the blank departure date and time will be replaced with the newly entered date and time.

`File.ReadAllLines()` is getting the txt data line by line and search for the keyword by row which `lines(indexNumber).Contains` is used. If `lines(indexNumber).Contains` returns true, then start replacing the empty departure date and time with the newly entered data using this code,

```
lines(i + 4) = "DepartureDate:" & strDepartureDate
lines(i + 5) = "DepartureTime:" & strDepartureTime
```

there is additional 4 and 5 with the index number because the index is currently pointed at the position of the `LicensePlate` and the `DepartureDate` and `DepartureTime` is `4` and `5` rows below the `LicensePlate` respectively.

> > ADDITIONAL:

```
Private Sub Display(ByVal strLicensePlate As String)
    Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("TextData.txt")
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        If lines(i).Contains(strLicensePlate) Then
            Console.WriteLine(lines(i + 1))
            Console.WriteLine(lines(i + 2))
            Console.WriteLine(lines(i + 3))
            Console.WriteLine(lines(i + 4))
            Console.WriteLine(lines(i + 5))
            File.WriteAllLines("TextData.txt", lines)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

the above code is displaying data. Just replace the `Console.WriteLine` with whatever variable you want to place the data either a `textbox` or `label`. And don't forget to add the `Display(strLicensePlate)` inside the `else` part after `For Next`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i only want to search for the license plate string inside of the TXT file, then display the that line as well as the 5 lines below into seperate text boxes, that i can edit.

Comment: Im a beginner so could you walk me through it a little